# Python, selenium - how to refresh page until item found?

Tags: python, html, selenium, refresh, zero-width-space

I am trying to refresg page until item appears but my code doesn't work (I took pattern on that: [python selenium keep refreshing until item found (Chromedriver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683692/python-selenium-keep-refreshing-until-item-found-chromedriver)).

Here is the code:

```
while True:
    try:
        for h1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("name-link"):
            text = h1.text.replace('\uFEFF', "")
            if "Puffy" in text:
                break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh
    else:
        for h1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("name-link"):
            text = h1.text.replace('\uFEFF', "")
            if "Puffy" in text:
                h1.click()
                break
        break
```

These fragment is because I have to find one item with the same class name and replace BOM with "" (`find_element_by_partial_link_text` didn't work).

```
for h1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("name-link"):
    text = h1.text.replace('\uFEFF', "")
    if "Puffy" in text:
        break
```

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are the items not on the page? Why does refreshing make them appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to get list of elements (`driver.find_elements_by_class_name()` might return list of elements or empty list - no exceptions) - you cannot get `NoSuchElementException` in this case, so `driver.refresh` will not be executed. Try below instead

```
while True:
    if any(["Puffy" in h1.text.replace('\uFEFF', "") for h1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("name-link")]):
        break
    else:
        driver.refresh
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Puffy')]").click()
```

Comment: But in which way can I click these element?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you also want to click it... Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Puffy')]").click()`

Comment: However, I do not need this (clicking) but your answer works. Thanks!